# Probability with Loaded Dice.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

**The Question**

Suppose that a die is biased (or loaded) so that 3 appears twice as often as each other number
but that the other five outcomes are equally likely. What is the probability that an odd number
appears when we roll this die?

**My Question**

The solution from my book is as follows:

We want to find the probability of the event $E = {1, 3, 5}$. By Exercise 2, we have
$p(1) = p(2) = p(4) = p(5) = p(6) = 1/7; p(3) = 2/7$.
It follows that
$p(E) = p(1) + p(3) + p(5) = 1/7 + 2/7 + 1/7 = 4/7$.

I'm wondering why is it that $p(1) = p(2) .. = 1/7$. Where do we get this number?

Comment: Let $p$ be the probability of getting a $1$. Then the probability of getting a $2$ is $p$, the probability of getting a $3$ is $2p$, the probability of getting a $4$ is $p$, and ditto for $5$ and $6$. Thus $p+p+2p+p+p+p=1$. So $7p=1$.

Comment: Odd number appears where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a normal die, the probability is 1/6 for each side, but since the 3 is twice as likely, then the probabilities are split up like this:

1: 1/7
2: 1/7
3: 2/7
4: 1/7
5: 1/7
6: 1/7

which equals 1 when summed.

Comment: Okay. Normally the probability is 1/6. If 3 is 2 times as likely, we have P(3) = 2/6. But that doesn't work because that would sum to 7/6. So why do we choose 7 as our sample space?

Comment: (5 * 1/7) + 2/7 = 7/7 = 1

Comment: Okay, so it adds correctly, but I'm still confused. What if it was an 8 sided die, biased so that 3 is 3x more likely to come up. How would we do it then?

Comment: It feels like we picked 7 because it sums nicely, but I'm not really sure what the probabilistic reasoning behind it is

Comment: @Dunka then the seven other numbers has probability $p$ and `3` has probability $3p$, which all add up to $1$, so: $7p+3p=1 \implies p=\frac 1 {10}$

Comment: The probabilistic reasoning is that the sum of probabilities of events that completely partition the space must equal one.

Comment: @GrahamKemp that was really well put. Thanks for clearing that up for me man!

Comment: Ok, you need to find 6 numbers that sum to 1. Five of them are the same, call it n, and the 6th number is 2n. So, we have 5n + 2n = 1. And so, 7n = 1. And finally, n=1/7.